# WriteLine/Print Arraylist with correct distance

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am looking for a way to print my result with a correct format in the console. I have an array arraylist I am filling with an array consisting out of three:

```
List<string[]> testlist = new List<string[]>();
string[] cars = { "AAAAA", "TTTTT", "CC" };
testlist .Add(cars);
string[] car2 = { "A", "T", "C" };
testlist .Add(car2);
```

when I just use a foreach with a WriteLine everything is limited with a standard space but I want an equal distance for each group like if I were using a gridview:

```
AAAAA  TTTTT  CC 
A      T      C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate maximum length of string and then write out strings padding them right with spaces (using `PadRight` function).

```cs
var maxLength = testlist.Max(l => l.Max(s => s.Length));
foreach (var l in testlist)
{
   foreach (var s in l)
       Console.Write(s.PadRight(maxLength + 1));
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```